# How to use unsafe context in Unity

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, clr, unsafe

I want to use `c++ code` in `c#` for Unity using CLR.

> The program works properly outside of unity, but inside of engine it gives me an error:
> *"cs0227: unsafe code requires the 'unsafe' command line option to be specified"*

I am really confused, because the project builds successfully in visual studio (without any errors or warnings). I have "**allow** **unsafe**" button activated.

```csharp
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class newspawn_real : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start () {
        unsafe
        {
            fixed (int * p = &bam[0, 0, 0])
            {
                CppWrapper.CppWrapperClass controlCpp = new CppWrapper.CppWrapperClass();
                controlCpp.allocate_both();
                controlCpp.fill_both();
                controlCpp.fill_wrapper();
            }
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: If something is unclear please tell me and I will correct it.

Comment: Since Unity is a black box, we don't really know what C# features are supported when code gets converted. A rough guess is unsafe stuff is not. Have you considered using `Marshal` class methods ?

Comment: do you mean dll  import? ' [DllImport("C++ unitshi.dll")] '
    static extern int add(int a, int b);'

Comment: No I mean all pointer types and pointer arithmetic, they certainly had to draw a line for the web player. But it seems that @Programmer answer allows you to do so.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You have to explicitly enable `unsafe` code in Unity. You can follow the steps below:

**1**. First step, Change **Api Compatibility Level**  to **.NET 2.0 Subset**.

[image: API Compatibility level]

**2**. Create a file in your `<Project Path>/Assets` directory and name it `smcs.rsp` then put `-unsafe` inside that file. Save and close that file.

[image: create smcs.rsp file]

- **Close and reopen Visual Studio and Unity Editor.**
- **You must restart both of them**.

It's worth noting that even after doing this and restarting both Unity and Visual Studio, if the problem is still there,

- Rename the `smcs.rsp` file to `csc.rsp`, `gmcs.rsp` or `mcs.rsp`

Restart Unity Editor and Visual Studio each time until you get one that works. For more details about the file name to use, refer to [Platform Dependent Compilation documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html).

Simple C# unsafe code that compiles after this.

```csharp
public class newspawn_real : MonoBehaviour
{
    unsafe static void SquarePtrParam(int* p)
    {
        *p *= *p;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        unsafe
        {
            int i = 5;
            // Unsafe method: uses address-of operator (&):
            SquarePtrParam(&i);
            Debug.Log(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much! this is the best forum on earth.

Comment: It's worth noting that we should use smcs.rsp (for .Net 2.0 Subset) or gmcs.rsp (for .Net 2.0)

Answer (score 6):

update:
on unity 2019 and forward, we don't have the 2.0 subset.
use 2.0 Standard.

and although mcs.rsp works, there is a warning noting that mcs is obsolete, and we should use csc.rsp instead.

but it actually works !

Answer (score 1):

Note that the error you get can be misleading:

> the Assets\Foo\Foo.cs(832,13): error CS0227: Unsafe code may
> only appear if compiling with /unsafe. Enable "Allow 'unsafe' code" in
> the inspector for 'Assets/Game.asmdef' to fix this error.

Even though Foo.cs is in Assets\Foo\Foo.asmdef and THAT is obviously the one that needs the switch set.