# Writing a value to a byte array without using C# unsafe nor fixed keyword

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

In C or C++, we can write the value of a variable directly onto a byte array.

```
int value = 3;
unsigned char array[100];
*(int*)(&array[10]) = value;
```

In C#, we also can do this by using `unsafe` and `fixed` keyword.

```
int value = 3;
byte[] array = new byte[100];
fixed(...) { ... }
```

However, Unity3D does not allow using `unsafe` nor `fixed`. In this case, what is the runtime cost-efficient way of doing it? I roughly guess it can be done with using a binary reader or writer class in .Net Core or .Net Framework, but I am not sure of it.

Comment: `char` array is not a `byte` array. Waht do you want to get?

Comment: You mean specifically how to write `int` in char array, or in general?

Comment: I changed the code. @Backs

Comment: @Evk Yes. I want to write `int` in the middle of char or byte array.

Comment: Unity supports `unsafe` and `fixed` keywords. See [Djeurissen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49444933/8407180)'s answer

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't use unsafe - you can just pack that `int` value yourself:

```
int value = 3;
var array = new char[100];
array[10] = (char)value; // right half
array[11] = (char)(value >> 16); // left half
```

Because `char` is basically `ushort` in C# (16-bit number). This should do the same as you would in C++ with

```
*(int*)(&array[10]) = value;
```

Another approach is using `BitConverter:

```
var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
array[10] = (char)BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 0);
array[11] = (char)BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 2);
```

But pay attention to endianess.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try to activate the unsafe keyword in Unity:
[How to use unsafe code Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39132079/how-to-use-unsafe-code-unity?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

That would spare you the effor to use any "hacks".