# Update Vector3 array from C++ native plugin

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, marshalling

`Marshal.Copy()` Method only supports a few array types. Now I only know how to copy from `IntPtr`(pointing to a float array from C++ code) to `float[]`.

```
IntPtr pvertices = GetVerticesFromCPP();
float[] vertices = new float[nVertices * 3];
Marshal.Copy(pvertices, vertices, 0, nVertices * 3);
```

But what I really want is a `UnityEngine.Vector3[]`.

Do I need to manually convert `float[]` to `UnityEngine.Vector3[]`? Or is there a simpler and faster way that directly do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Do I need to manually convert float[] to UnityEngine.Vector3[]? Or is
>   there a simpler and faster way that directly do this?

Yes, you have to do that manually but there is a better way to do this.

I will assume that you need to modify a `Vector3` on the native side then return the result. There is no need to use `float` array for this. Just create a `Vector3` struct on the C++ side then use pointer to pass it between C++ and C#. *Do not return the `Vector3` array from C++*, create it on the C# side, then pass it to the C++ function to modify and apply the changes to the argument.

**C++:**

This requires that you [enable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39132664/3785314) the unsafe keyword in Unity.

```
struct Vector3
{
     float x;
     float y;
     float z;
};
```

then your function:

```
extern "C" void UpdateVectorArray(Vector3* vecArray, int vecSize)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < vecSize; ++i)
    {
        //Simply modify each Vector reference
        Vector3 &vec = vecArray[i];
        vec.x = 11;
        vec.y = 20;
        vec.z = 55;
    }
}
```

**C#:**

```
[DllImport("Plugin Name")]
static unsafe extern void UpdateVectorArray(Vector3* vecArray, int vecSize);


void UpdateVectorArray(Vector3[] vecArray)
{
    unsafe
    {
        //Pin array then send to C++
        fixed (Vector3* vecPtr = vecArray)
        {
            UpdateVectorArray(vecPtr, vecArray.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

Get vertices from model, send to C++ and modify it the re-assign the modified mesh:

```
void Start()
{
    Mesh mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;

    Vector3[] vertices = mesh.vertices;
    UpdateVectorArray(vertices);

    //Re-assign the modified mesh
    mesh.vertices = vertices;
    mesh.RecalculateBounds();
}
```

---

To avoid using the `unsafe` keyword in Unity use the `[In, Out]`  attribute.

```
[DllImport("Plugin Name")]
static extern void UpdateVectorArray([In, Out] Vector3[] vecArray, int vecSize);

void Start()
{
    Mesh mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;

    Vector3[] vertices = mesh.vertices;
    UpdateVectorArray(vertices, vertices.Length);

    mesh.vertices = vertices;
    mesh.RecalculateBounds();
}
```

The C++ side remains the-same. You can also use the [GCHandle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49486419/3785314) to pin the array and avoid using the  `unsafe` keyword  but the `unsafe` keyword solution is better and faster.

Comment: Awesome! This is much better than I could expect.

Comment: Glad you find it helpful. Had to change the title to make it easier to find it