# Accessing values of an unmanaged C++ pointer to pointer in C#

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, marshalling, unmanaged

I want to use c++ code in my C# scripts for rendering some objects in unity 3d.

I have compiled the C++ script as a dll (lammps.dll) and have written a wrapper C# script to invoke a few functions from C++ script.

I am able to access void* and int* pointer successfully by doing the following:

Example:

```
  C++ prototype:
  void *lammps_extract_global(void *ptr, char *name);

  Equivalent C# prototype (in CSharpLibrary.cs file):

   DllImport("lammps.dll", EntryPoint = "lammps_extract_gloabl", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall);
   public static extern IntPtr lammps_extract_global(IntPtr ptr, [MarshalAs(UnmamanegType.LPStr)]String name);
```

**Then I compile the C# file as a file which produces CSharpLibrary.dll**

In another C# script I am using CSharpLibrary wrapper to access C++ functions as:

```
  1.  First define lmp_ptr as,
  var lmp_ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.Sizeof(typeof(System.IntPtr)));

  2.  Get lmp_ptr from C++ and dereference it as,
  var deref1 = (System.IntPtr)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lmp_ptr, typeof(System.IntPtr))

  3.  Then use deref1 to get natmPtr as, 
  System.IntPtr natmPtr = CSharpLibrary.CSharpLibrary.lammps_extract_global(deref1, "natoms");


   4. Convert natmPtr to an integer as,
    int nAtom = (int)Marshal.PtrToStructure(natmPtr, typeof(int))
```

Step 4 gives me appropriate value of nAtom.

I want to do the same thing as done for **nAtom** to another float pointer to pointer matrix storing positions.

```
   I did this to get the float pointer to pointer reference in C#
```

**Considering lammps_extract_atom has been defined similar to the function explain above, we have**

```
   System.IntPtr posPtr = CSharpLibrary.CSharpLibrary.lammps_extract_atom(deref1, "x")

   Here posPtr is a float** value being returned from C++
```

**Similar statement in C++ would have looked like**

```
  float** posPtr = (double**)(lammps_extract_atom)(void *lmp_ptr, char *name)
```

Comment: You want to return float array from C++ to C#?

Comment: Yes I want to access the elements of float** array in C#

Comment: Create the array in C# and update it in C++. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44424465/3785314) post. That's the most peformant way to do this. If you want to return Vector3, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53178114/3785314) post too. Not a good idea to return non Object pointer from C++. Again, this is due to performance (memory allocation.

Comment: I cannot pass the C# array to C++ since the C++ code is quite complex and do not exactly know what is the entry point of initialization of the array. But I do know that the return value from the C++ function of interest is the desired value of interest. Thanks!!

Comment: *"I cannot pass the C# array to C++ since the C++ code is quite complex"* That doesn't make any sense and yes, you can. I am not sure what you mean by entry point of initialization of the array but you can can pass C# array to C++ from the Awake or Start function to initialize the array if you actually read the post I linked. If you still decide to do it your own way, don't forget to free/delete it on the C++ side and also on the C# side. Goodluck!

Comment: You can use function Marshal.PtrToStruct  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.ptrtostructure?view=netframework-3.5

Comment: @LiuHao Which requires `GCHandle.Alloc`, `GCHandle.Free` and freeing the array on the native just like programmer said.